# Adding a rake action to a capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have a rake task named : `at_deployment:shops_assets_compile`

Is it possible to call this task every time cap deploy is called? It needs to work for production and staging without adding new command line params to `cap #{env} deploy`.

EDIT : added the following to capistrano, but it does not seems to be executed :

```
task :special_assets,:roles => :app do
  run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake at_deployment:shops_assets_compile"
end
```

Ful deploy.rb :

```
####Added for multiple environnements
set :stages, %w(prodtest production)
set :default_stage, "prodtest"
require "capistrano/ext/multistage"
require "rvm/capistrano"
require "bundler/capistrano"
load "deploy/assets"
# require  'capistrano/rails'

set :repodomain,"***"
set :user,"***"
set :application, "***"
set :repository,"#{user}@#{repodomain}:/srv/outils/repos/#{application}"

set :scm, 'git'
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

# if you want to clean up old releases on each deploy uncomment this:
# after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
set :use_sudo, false
default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :keep_releases, 5
# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts



# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:key => "value", 
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
task :special_assets,:roles => :app do
  run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV= #{rails_env}bundle exec rake at_deployment:shops_assets_compile"
end

after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
```

Comment: post full `deploy.rb` please

Comment: you alway can use `after` and `before` hook like `after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"`, something like `after "deploy:update_code", "special_assets"`.